# is it possible to catch fatal error php on include file?

Tags: php, error-handling, include

Here's what I want to do just if a fatal error is in the file I don't want the script to halt execution

```
try { 
require "somethin.php"
} catch(...) {}
```

Would some method of `file_get_contents()` and `eval()` be a way around

Comment: Why didn't you try it first?

Comment: In fairness he probably did try it, haha did you catch that?

Comment: @DaveChen You are saying "probably" because, he did not give any hints  whether if he did/or not. So, who is the actaully [censored] here?hmm. 

Sadly, I read his disgusting comment.

Comment: For me, I did try it, http://puu.sh/3dF22.png and it still erred, so that leads the conclusion that he did try it before posting.

Comment: @DaveChen So for every question asked in SO with the OP failing to specify whether he tried/or not. We are supposed to try it out for them by ourselves? hmm.. interesting.

Comment: Yes! I was going to assume that the code worked fine, but it clearly didn't. Unless you're clear that the code works without testing it yourself, don't ask if they've tried it. :)

Comment: A fatal error is like the word suggests fatal. There is no *sane* way to try to recover from this.

Comment: Why don't you use `include` rather than `require`, and register an exception error handler? Require is explicitly designed to throw a fatal error. Include does the same but with a warning.

Answer (score 6):

*Notice - this does not answer the poster's question. The ugly reality is you cannot recover from a fatal error but this works for other errors*

require doesn't throw an exception but rather triggers an error by default.

To have php throw exceptions you have to register an error exception handler.

You can find an example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)

But basically it

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

With this in play it's possible to catch and deal with the error as you see fit

Comment: I'd like to mention that it's probably better to check if the file can be read before requiring it, no?

Comment: @DaveChen That's one approach ... I like this better because it's only one hit on the filesystem

Comment: It's also worth noting that this will cause almost all php errors to throw exceptions (a good thing in my opinion) except for parse time errors

Comment: like syntax errors? Having all PHP errors/warnings throw exceptions, oh gosh it's like Java all over again.

Comment: This doesn't catch fatal errors (which really shouldn't be catched in the first place).

Comment: Depends on what kind of fatal error... again parse errors it wont because the exception handler can't be installed if the file in question can't be parsed.

Comment: but those errors should be able to be easily found in development.

Comment: No a fatal error is a fatal error. Which is what this question is about. It is both in the title and the question itself. As such this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The bad thing is that this causes E_NOTICE and the like to become fatal unless you rig you error handler conditionally throw if the error is of a certain type.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 Follow the link, read the docs. This deals with fatal errors

Comment: No it really doesn't deal with fatal errors. It handles warnings / notices, but not fatal errors: http://codepad.org/4nzzYQSG

Comment: @Orangepill - 1) it doesn't inherently make anything fatal - it makes things catchable (if you don't catch the exception, then it's fatal) 2) don't know about you, but when my developers put something out to production one of the aims is to have no E_NOTICE and no E_WARNING at all, so this wouldn't be a problem anyway.

Comment: @HorusKol I agree but I thought it should be stated. After doing this stuff that would have squeaked by with notices would now fall down.

Comment: @Orangepill - and my thought on that is "good" ;) - I've elevated the error reporting on a number of legacy scripts before now, and got rid of all sorts of deprecated stuff like ereg, and bad practices like uninitiated variables - if the final script is better written at the end of it (even if it means more work), what's the problem?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 Point to you on this one...

Comment: Yay moar intarnet points! :-) Thanks for undeleting the answer and adding the disclaimer.

Answer (score 5):

No there is really no sane way to catch (uncatchable ;-) ) fatal errors in PHP. So there is also no sane way to recover from this. Which makes sense because it is a fatal error.

Basically what PHP is saying is: this is something you cannot / should not try to recover from.

Note that also [@Orangepill's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17054958/508666) won't work for fatal errors: http://codepad.org/4nzzYQSG

Now if you would want to do something when a fatal error happens (e.g. send an email to you to inform you of this) you may want to look into: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146171/508666

Comment: +1 My solution below while useful won't even throw something given the example above.

Comment: +1 for making me proud. (even though, I don't know what you guys are talking about :P )

Comment: So what is the right thing to do ... nix my answer or just but a banner across the top stating it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Orangepill Close it, as not a real question

Comment: nah the question is good... there just is not an answer the the op wants.

Comment: @Orangepill It may still be useful to someone coming across this question. So I would 1+ the banner idea if it is clear you cannot catch fatal errors, but at least recover from some gracefully.